# How do I get TiddlySnip to work in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, tiddlywiki

Since Google stopped supporting Notebooks, I decided to look for alternatives and so I gave TiddlyWiki + TiddlySnip a shot.  However, when trying to install TiddlySnip2.1, I'm getting this error:

*"TiddlySnip" will not be installed because it does not provide secure updates*

I followed the procedure specified in the site which is to add tiddlysnip.com in the Allowed sites-Add ons list but it still won't work.

And to add insult to injury, the support for the extension has been stopped as well.

My final workaround is to use an older version(1.21-beta), which I was able to find, but I'm finding it a bit unstable.

Did anyone have any success with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Google's notebook works just fine.
They have only stopped development on it, the app still works as well as before.

Comment: I too have the same problem installing on Firefox 3.5.7.  Where did you get the 1.21-beta version?  How difficult do you think it would be to edit the addon just to get it working?

Comment: I had a similar problem using TiddlySnip on newer versions of Firefox. You just need to disable the firefox check like so:  
a) http://cybernetnews.com/helpful-tip-firefox-secure-updates-extension-warning/
b) http://blog.ideashower.com/post/15147321440/how-to-disable-will-not-be-installed-because-it-does-not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eureka! Google has saved me! Their google group has a post on how to shoehorn it into Firefox 3.5.x: http://groups.google.com/group/tiddlysnip/browse_thread/thread/e5edef97dec18a17/ce49452f6397083a?lnk=gst&q=does+not+provide+secure+updates#ce49452f6397083a

Answer (score 0):

Right Stumproot, however I just feel the need to look for alternatives.

OT, I went as far as going into the irc channel of tiddlywiki to find out and it seems that there's no other way around this issue than to use the older version.

I think that the TW community still plans to continue developing TiddlySnip but for now it's on hold so TW users will just have to make do with the beta version.